# Как программно анимировано сменить цвет у Shape?

Tags: android, анимация, shape

Есть shape (back.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="85dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="5dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid
        android:color="#FF0000">
    </solid>
    <size
        android:height="200dp"
        android:width="200dp">
    </size>
</shape>
```

Этот shape является фоном у TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back" />
```

В итоге нужно, чтобы цвет этого кольца (shape) вокруг текста (textview) постоянно анимировано (плавно) менялся на случайный (randomcolor - решено).

Нужен [такой](http://tjvantoll.com/demos/2012-02-20/basic.html) эффект смены цвета для shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(textView, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE).setDuration(250);
        objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        objectAnimator.start();
```

Как-то так. Этот код изменит цвет фона с анимированием.

Comment: Мне, по сути, нужно изменить не цвет фона textview, а цвет Drawable, который является фоном textview.

Т.е.  

    textView.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));
drawable =  textView.getBackground();

И вот этому объекту Drawable нужно плавно менять цвет от текущего к случайному.

Comment: @Левон Нужно создать атрибут, например, drawableBackColor, определить его в Theme и подставить в описание Drawable. Дальше с тем кодом сверху вместое textView подставить объект Drawable, вместо "backgroundColor" написать "drawableBackColor". Возможно, поможет :3

Comment: @Deadkenny Спасибо огромное! Всё получилось. Обошёлся без атрибутов.

                currentColor=randColor();
                Drawable drawable = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content).getBackground();
                ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawable, "color",previousColor, currentColor).setDuration(2000);
                objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                objectAnimator.start();
                previousColor=currentColor;

Так как цвета случайные запоминаем предыдущий цвет в previousColor.

Comment: @Deadkenny Всё это записал в  timer.schedule(new RunTimer(), 0, 2000); для постоянной смены цвета. Тоже работает. Но такое ощущение, что поджирает память (по крайней мере она растёт в MemoryMonitor (Android Studio)). Будет ли лучше цикл в отдельном потоке?

Comment: @Левон попробуйте ArgbEvaluator создавать один раз в Activity и использовать его повторно. Скорее всего, он пожирает :3